# ES6 classes extends a class with returning constructor

Tags: javascript, es6-class

In the following code I have an unexpected behaviour for me. I was waited to see the method A2::method() to be called, but it is A0::method() instead.
More tests showed me that if A1 returns something, it will keep public prop from A2 but forget all methods from A2. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Is there a workaround

```js
class A0 {
  method() {
    return "from A0 " + this.prop
  }
}

class A1 {
  constructor() {
    return new A0;
  }
}


class A2 extends A1 {
  constructor(v) {
    super()
    console.log('here')
    this.prop = v;
  }
  prop = 42;

  method() {
    return "from A2 " + this.prop
  }
}
const a = new A2(42);
console.log(a.prop, a.method())
```

Result

```
[LOG]: "here" 
[LOG]: 42,  "from A0 42"
```

Expected

```
[LOG]: "here" 
[LOG]: 42,  "from A2 42"
```

Comment: Well yes you can return anything from a `constructor`, you are breaking inheritance by doing this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by making the `A1` constructor return an `A0` object?

Comment: This is a extreme simplified extract from a code I tried

Comment: Sure, but fundamentally you're making `new X` return a `Y`, which is at least .... surprising ... for anyone trying to use these classes. What's the goal of that? I could see some argument for a `Proxy` object, but you wouldn't be seeing what you're seeing with a `Proxy`. It's just that we could probably offer a better approach if we knew why you were doing this. (That, and curiousity. :-) )

Comment: In the very original code, I try to find a way to make a multi-inheritence code by passing args to all constructor... And this broke my latest solution that worked perfectly... Except the methods from the final object . So I'll keep on searching an other solution.

Comment: And proxy don't help me as I do want to use private member (I mean hash-members) and proxies are not good for that (it doesn't have the same behaviour that real inheritance)

Comment: I guess the pattern you're looking for is the "mixin"

Comment: I tried many mixins implementations, none were 100% satisfying to me needs (private props and methods, method overridings and inheritance, args to each constructors, syntax easy to transform for a very specific transpiler…)

Comment: @Guile - Yeah, mixins don't play well with advanced `class` features. Composition may be what you want, or a facade over a composed instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) says:

> The constructor method may have a return value. While the base class
> may return anything from its constructor, the derived class must
> return an object or undefined, or a TypeError will be thrown. If the
> parent class constructor returns an object, that object will be used
> as the this value on which class fields of the derived class will be
> defined. This trick is called "return overriding", which allows a
> derived class's fields (including private ones) to be defined on
> unrelated objects.

In your example, the object you have created is not an actual instance of `A1` or `A2`

```js
class A0 {
  method() {
    return "from A0 " + this.prop
  }
}

class A1 {
  constructor() {
    return new A0;
  }
}


class A2 extends A1 {
  constructor(v) {
    super()
    console.log('here')
    this.prop = v;
  }
  prop = 42;

  method() {
    return "from A2 " + this.prop
  }
}
const a = new A2(42);
console.log(a.prop, a.method());

console.log('Is a instance of A0:', a instanceof A0); // true
console.log('Is a instance of A1:', a instanceof A1); // false
console.log('Is a instance of A2:', a instanceof A2); // false
```

In other terms, you have created an object that does not have `A1` or `A2` in its prototype chain, but the `A2` constructor still attached `prop` to it.

Comment: …and notice that if you `console.log(this instanceof A1, this instanceof A2)` inside the `A1` constructor, you still have the instance with the expected prototype chain available.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know these specific fact which seems unusual at first glance (this can be a hard thing to debug as well!)